# Help proving Sylow's Theorem order 58

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Prove that every group of order 58 is not simple. 
So I know that 58 = 2 ⋅ 29. I assume G is simple. I'm having trouble using the Sylow Theorems to show that this is not Simple. In particular, computing the number of sylow groups and using that to show the group isn't Simple

Comment: Hint: What is the index of a Sylow-29?

Comment: What do Sylow's theorems tell you about the number of subgroups of order $29$? Can you see that if a group has just a single subgroup of a given order, then that subgoup must be normal? (its conjugates are subgroups of the same order as itself, but there is only one such subgroup)

Comment: so far I have 

Let G be a group with |G| = 58 = 2 ⋅ 29. Sylows theorem tells us that there exists Syl_p(G) for each prime p|(G)

Comment: Is this right? Let n_29 be the number of sylow 29 subgroups. n_29 = 1+29k and n_29 | 2 =>(implies) n_29 = 1. Thus sylow -29 subgroups is normal. => G is not simple @Mark Bennet

Comment: That looks good to me. There are various techniques commonly used with Sylow's theorems, and counting subgroups is one. Explore the Sylow Theory tag or the list of related questions you see when you bring this one up to see one further examples.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P \in Syl_{29}(G)$. Such a $P$ exists by Sylow's (First) Theorem (or just by Cauchy's Theorem). Then $|G:P|=2$ and it is basic group theory knowledge that subgroups of index $2$ are normal. So $G$ cannot be simple.